# How can I display nested component with React router?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I’m using the last release of React Router and I want to know what is the best solution to show different component that are nested in a parent component.

I’ll try to explain myself better.

I have a route `R` with  path `/r1`.
This route loads component `A`.
Component A has inside others 3 components `B`, `C` and `D` that I should show in the same page with component `A` only when the user press a specific button in component `A`.
So I want to be able to add a description in route `R` to manage this. For example to show component `B` the router could be `/r1/b`.

Now I did this with a state variable inside component `A` but I think should be better if I can use some React Router property.

Thanks

Comment: having the route pattern as `/r1/:component` lets you decide the nested component at render time

Comment: @NikosM. how can I do this with a functional component? My component A is a functional component and I should always load A and one of the others 3 depending on the :component. Can you write an example for me?

Answer (score 0):

You can create nested routes component, and it will manage nested routes.

```
export default function NestedRoutes() {
    return (
        <Switch>
            <Redirect exact from={"/r1"} to={`/r1/A`} />

            <Route path={`/r1/A`}>
                <ComponentA />
            </Route>

            <Route path={`/r1/B`}>
                <ComponentB />
            </Route>

            // Or to some not found component
            <Redirect to="/r1/A" />
        </Switch>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Switch with my route entries. The problem was that I didn't know how to render a component that I wanted to pass by props to another component.

I added a prop component to my parent component A and in my route I wrote something like this:

```
<Route path="/r1/hub/A" render={() => <A /> //this render only A
<Route path="/r1/hub/A/B" render={() => <A component={B} /> //this render A with B
```

In component A I used `React.createElement` to render component B with others properties that component A has to inject.